# Change step number to a mat-icon in an Angular Material Stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create an Angular Material stepper, but instead of a number inside the bubble I want to use mat-icons, how should I do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`matStepperIcon`](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepperIcon) to override the icon.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
  <mat-step label="Step 1" state="minus">
    <p>Minus</p>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Step 2" state="plus">
    <p>Plus</p>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>

  <ng-template matStepperIcon="minus">
    <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="plus">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Add to the component:

```
providers: [{
  provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {displayDefaultIndicatorType: false}
}]
```

Comment: This would only work with angular version>=7 since it was introduced after that.

Comment: Thank you. I was not paying attention to providers and was wondering why it is not working.