# reverse mat-stepper step numbering

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I want to reverse the numbering of the mat-stepper steps.

Currently each `mat-step` contains a `mat-step-icon`, which contains a `mat-step-icon-content`, which contains a `span` element of class `ng-star-inserted`, within which there is this step's index, starting from 1 to n, n being the number of steps.
How can I change the numbers in the `span` elements to be in reverse order - so that the first step will be labeled with n, and the last step with 1?

I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560728/how-to-change-angular-material-stepper-step-numbers-to-any-icon-or-text) how to remove the original context entirely, and place a constant label in each step, but I didn't see a way to set this label to be different for each step, and dependent on the step index.

Thanks,